# Issue with migrating database Room android

Tags: android, sqlite, database-migration, android-room

I am having issues with Android Room. I am trying to migrate from a pre-populated SQLITE database.

```
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Database;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.migration.Migration;

@Database(entities = {Attributes.class}, version = 2)

public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract AttributesDao attributesDao();

    Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "Attributes.db")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();

    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        }
    };

}
```

The line of code:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "Attributes.db")
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();
```

Is throwing lots of errors. Any idea what could be causing this?

Errors: [Build Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JtX8.png)

Comment: `public abstract AttributesDao attributesDao();` remove the () here and it will magically start working

Comment: That unfortunately hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: check for other typos